# ¿Cómo podría hacer que se escojan diez números de un array y que sean distintos entre sí?

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, random

Lo he intentado hacer a través de este código, pero sin embargo, no es eficaz al 100% lo es en un 65% cosa que es poco, ¿cómo lo podría hacer? Saludos.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    
    const aon  = [
    
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
    
    ];
    var one = Math.floor(Math.random() * aon.length);
    var two = Math.floor(Math.random() * aon.length);
    var third = Math.floor(Math.random() * aon.length);
    var four = Math.floor(Math.random() * aon.length);
    var five = Math.floor(Math.random() * aon.length);
    var six = Math.floor(Math.random() * aon.length);
    var seven = Math.floor(Math.random() * aon.length);
    var eight = Math.floor(Math.random() * aon.length);
    var nine = Math.floor(Math.random() * aon.length);
    var ten = Math.floor(Math.random() * aon.length);
    
    if(one == two || one == third || one == four || one == five || one == six || one == seven || one == eight || one == nine || one == ten){
        var mod = Math.floor(Math.random() * aon.length); 
        console.log(mod);
    } 
    if(two == one || two == third || two == four || two == five || two == six || two == seven || two == eight || two == nine || two == ten || two == mod){
        var modi = Math.floor(Math.random() * aon.length); 
        console.log(modi);
    } 
    if(third == two || third == third || third == four || third == five || third == six || third == seven || third == eight || third == nine || third == ten || third == modi || third == mod){
        var third = Math.floor(Math.random() * aon.length); 
        console.log(third);
    } 





});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una buena opción para asignar 10 números diferentes es:

```js
// Asigna un número que no se encuentre asignado
const rand = (limit, arr) => {
  let n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (limit + 1));
  return arr.includes(n) ? rand(limit, arr) : n;
};

// Asigna 10 números diferentes
const arrayFill = limit => {
    const arr = [...Array(10)];
    arr.forEach( (_, i) => {
        arr[i] = rand(limit, arr);
    });
  return arr;
};

console.log(arrayFill(10)); // Números entre 0 y 10
console.log(arrayFill(100)); // Números entre 0 y 100
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mg5frj6p/